# .htaccess empty page if mutiple request

Tags: php, string, .htaccess

Good afternoon,

I have a qestions about my .htaccess file wchich is in the root of ery folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /ery/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^menu/contact/?$ contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^events/(.+)$ events.php?events=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^menu/(.+)$ navigation.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

## request example - http://localhost/ery/categories/activities
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^categories/(.+)?$ categories.php?categories=$1 [NC,L]

## request example - http://localhost/ery/categories/activities/activities-for-care
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^categories/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ categories.php?categories=$1&article=$2 [NC]
```

When I click on the link `http://localhost/ery/categories/activities/activities-for-care` I am getting empty page. I think that the request for sql is not correct but how can I fix that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: **1.** You don't need to put the same .htaccess in every folder. It's enough to put it in the root-folder. **2.** You can remove all `RewriteCond ... !-f` and `!-d` and just keep the first pair. **3.** Have you checked your error log? An empty page is usually what happens on PHP-errors, when `display_errors` are turned off.

Comment: ery is the name of the folder. There is just one file of .htaccess

Comment: But I have the feeling that the string of the request .htaccess is not compiler properrly because the activities-for-care is the string.

Comment: Sorry. Misread "ery folder" as "every folder" :) But you can check the other points I made. Specially the one about checking your error log. Without that, all we can do here is guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I find out why I got the empty page. There is a clash because it is testing the same word of **categories**.

```
## request example - http://localhost/ery/categories/activities/
RewriteRule ^categories/(.+)?$ categories.php?categories=$1 [NC,L]

## request example - http://localhost/ery/categories/activities/activities-for-care/
RewriteRule ^categories/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ categories.php?categories=$1&article=$2 [NC,L]
```

if I chenge te second rule like so

```
## request example - http://localhost/ery/category/activities/activities-for-care/
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ categories.php?categories=$1&article=$2 [NC,L]
```

then I am getting the result of the page. But I guess that for the SEO is not good idea. How can I do correctly? Thank you.